# Extracting information from C headers (functions, structs, ...)

Tags: c, parsing, header

I would love to write more software with [V](https://github.com/vlang/v) but having to painstakingly copytype the APIs I would love to use really sucks. So I have been looking into how to change that. One option is [SWIG](https://github.com/swig/swig), but just for grabbing the definitions of functions, structs/unions and globals, it's quite over-the-top, since I only need the tool to generate something akin to a V source file.

So I was thinking of just using a C99 compliant parser like TinyCC and seeing if I could extract an AST out of that. Unfortunately, this has not been as easy as I was hoping it would be because TinyCC doesn't just parse C into an AST, it already prepares information for compilation. So hacking the parser out of it is tricky, at best.

Since there are tools that are meant to statically analyze code coverage or aid in IDE support, I wouldn't be surprised if someone had done something similar already, even if it is just to jump to a definition at the very least.

Hence, my question: Would it be safe to parse C with a parser library like [MPC](https://github.com/orangeduck/mpc)? Or is there a better, more forward alternative that you can suggest?

Comment: Suggest you ask at Software Recommendations, for questions like this: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/18123/101

Comment: Both gcc and clang include mechanisms to parse the source into something more manageable. Clang even includes a library.